# How to write a PowerShell script which export ACL permissions from all the containers of all GEn2 Storage account in subscription?

Tags: azure, powershell, acl, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-storage-account

We have multiple subscriptions with dozens of resource groups and each RG contains Gen 2 storage account. We need to export ACL permissions from all the containers of all the subfolders in each storage account i.e. Gen2. I have written 1 script which gives me ACL permissions of only parent folder not the sub-folders. Any suggestions to export ACL permissions of sub-folders as well?

```
Connect-AzAccount


$storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount 


$results = foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) 


  {

    $containers = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $storageAccount.Context

    foreach ($container in $containers) 

{

        $filesystem = Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $storageAccount.Context -FileSystem 
        $container.Name
        $s = $storageAccount.storageaccountname
        $r = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
        $filesystemname = $container.Name
        $aclpermission = $filesystem.ACL.Permissions -join ","
        $aclaccesscontroltype=$filesystem.ACL.AccessControlType -join ","

        [PSCustomObject]@{
            StorageAccountName = $s
            ResourceGroupName = $r 
            ContainerName = $filesystemname
            ACLpermission = $aclpermission
            ACLaccesscontroltype=$aclaccesscontroltype
        }
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path "output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: In order to get the subfolders you can use Get-ChildItem.  So you would have another internal loop once you've got the filesystem variable populated.
$Folders = $filesystem | gci -directory -recurse
Then you can loop through the folders.

Comment: Can you please explain this a bit more?

Comment: ``` $filesystem = Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $storageAccount.Context -FileSystem ``` is only returning the top level folder.  You want to loop through all of the subfolders in that folder right?  So once you have that folder you need to get a collection of subfolders using get-childitem.  Then when you can iterate through that collection before moving on to the next container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to write a PowerShell script that exports ACL permissions from all the containers of all GEn2 Storage accounts in subscription? Any suggestions to export ACL permissions of sub-folders as well?

You can use the below PowerShell script to export ACL permissions of **`Container`** and **`subfolders.`**

**Script:**

```
Connect-AzAccount

$storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount 

$results = foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
    $containers = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $storageAccount.Context
    foreach ($container in $containers) {
        $filesystem = Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $storageAccount.Context -FileSystem $container.Name
        $subfolders = Get-AzDataLakeGen2ChildItem -Context $storageAccount.Context -FileSystem $container.Name -Path "/"
        foreach ($subfolder in $subfolders) {
            $subfolderitem = Get-AzDataLakeGen2Item -Context $storageAccount.Context -FileSystem $container.Name -Path $subfolder.Name
            $s = $storageAccount.storageaccountname
            $r = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
            $filesystemname = $container.Name
            $subfoldername = $subfolder.Name
            $aclpermission = $filesystem.ACL.Permissions -join ","
            $subfolderaclpermission = $subfolderitem.ACL.Permissions -join ","
            $aclaccesscontroltype = $filesystem.ACL.AccessControlType -join ","
            $subfolderaccesscontroltype = $subfolderitem.ACL.AccessControlType -join ","
    
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                StorageAccountName = $s
                ResourceGroupName = $r 
                ContainerName = $filesystemname
                Subfoldername = $subfoldername
                ACLpermission = $aclpermission
                ACLaccesscontroltype = $aclaccesscontroltype
                SubfolderACLpermission = $subfolderaclpermission
                SubfolderaccessControlType = $subfolderaccesscontroltype
            }
        }
    }
}

$results | Export-Csv -Path "output.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The above PowerShell script retrieves information about **`Azure Data Lake Gen2 items`** and exports the results to a CSV file. It iterates through each **`storage account`**, **`container,`** and **`subfolder`**, and retrieves the ACL information for each item. Finally, it creates a custom object that contains the relevant information and exports it to a CSV file.

**Output:**
[image]